# Uninstall Chromedriver Windows 10

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to remove completely chromedriver from my computer in order to be able to upgrade to a higher version because I have an error message :

> selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message:
> session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome
> version 83

I made long researches on the subject unfortunately it's either not adapted, or things that don't work, I deleted all the chromedriver I could find, I looked for commands like pip uninstall the problem is that with pip it uninstalls but when I make chromedriver -version I get the version that makes me have the error message

I have chocolatey, so I searched for an order to uninstall the package unfortunately I found nothing, and/or nothing worked.

Comment: Could you delete all the chrome drivers available in your machine?. And you have to build your project again after adding the new version web driver.

Comment: When I type chromedriver in my search bar, I don't have any folder, file, executable called chromedriver but as I said when I make (in cmd) chromedriver  -version I have the 83 version, which causes an error

Comment: Write executable_path of your chromedriver in the code.

Comment: I did not understand everything ^^ 
I have to write in my main.py : 
 executable_path : <the path of my chromedriver executable file> ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, there are two ways that you can try to solve the problem when you use Windows 10.

1. Find the chromedirver.exe and delete it.
   I know you have tried a lot, but this is another method.

   - run `C:\>chromedirver.exe` in the Command Prompt `cmd` which will make the process of chromedirver.exe running
     [image]
   - Open the running program path via Windows Task-Manager. See this [url](https://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Windows-10&faq=152#S2) for more info
     [image]
   - delete the file
2. Set your chromedriver.exe path in the code.

   - see this [url](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/driver_requirements/) to know how to set `executable_path`

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to uninstall the chromedriver with any available options on the internet. Then I stubmled upon the function itself.

```
webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="../yourpath/chromedriver.exe")
```

You can copy the newly downloaded chromedriver and store it in a location, and provide the location as an argument to the `Chrome()` function.

It solved the issue for me! Hope it helps.

Comment: It worked perfectly for me. From now on I save the webdriver.exe in the same file as my python script and only change the file version in the same path. Thanks!

Comment: Could either of you please share the code for how you did this?